# WinForms dataGridView event handler before row selection changes

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, datagridview

I want to save my dataGridView when another row is clicked but the problem is that because the row is changed the data gets saved in the wrong row. Please help.

Comment: can you explain briefly.

Comment: @senthilkumar2185 I want to know if there is an event handler that triggers when a row is clicked but before the rowIndex changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void dgvDesign_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    MsgBox(dgvDesign.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("column1").Value);
}
```

While you click grid It will show previous clicked row rowindex value.